# Mass conversion of .numbers files to .csv

Tags: applescript, numbers

I have a lot of files with a .numbers file extension, and I need to convert them to .csv, so I can more easily work with the data. There are probably about 1000 of them, so opening them in numbers and exporting each one individually is not an option.

Is there some sort of terminal function that could do the job?

---

Update:

An AppleScript might be able to do the job, and the one provided by Frysk in the comments below gets close. However, it only works one file at a time.

To work in mass the script needs:

- to loop through all the .numbers files in a directory
- to write csv files to a specified directory

Comment: No but an AppleScript could be written to automate the open in numbers and export

Comment: Zamzar does this [online](http://www.zamzar.com/convert/numbers-to-csv/) and has drag-and-drop for multiple files. Free version has 50mb limit. Converted files are emailed. I used it a few times for simple conversions.

Comment: [Here is the AppleScript](https://iworkautomation.com/numbers/document-export.html) to convert .numbers to .csv - does that help you, @Josh?

Comment: Another converting script. https://gist.github.com/kfriend/6463172

Comment: I've tried working with the applescript provided in the link by @Frysk but I don't know how to modify it loop through all the spreadsheets in a specified directory or to make it export the .csv to a specific directory.

Comment: The one I posted isn't working for me, either. Have you tried bret's link?

Comment: Not yet. But it looks like it only works for the file that is currently open in Numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automator is the tool for the job.

You can do a "watch me do" and have it export an already open file to a new folder as csv. Then stop recording the script.

At that point, you can add an acton to process files and folders so the script will one by one open each file, save it to the new location. As long as the names aren't conflicting, you would have an easy tool.

Better would be to script the actual export options, but start simple and then add the batch processing.